# Extend ObjC class with Swift extension Causes crashes when released to Appstore

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui, swift-extensions, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have an objective project and when I'm extending the project to Swift, It works fine when locally testing it and also when testing it over testflight.

But after submitting the app to the appstore and when users download it and use, I see crash reports coming from the Sentry related with the swift extensions created over the objective-c class.

I'm unable to reproduce this locally.

This is the code I'm using

Example Objective-C class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Settings : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

- (BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

**Settings.m**

```
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation Settings {
    NSDictionary *_dictionary;
}

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dictionary = dictionary;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [[_dictionary objectForKey:key] boolValue];
}
@end
```

**Swift extension**

**Settings+extension.swift**

```
import Foundation
extension Settings {

    @objc public func isFirstProperty() -> Bool {
        return self.bool(forKey: "isFirstProperty")
    }

    @objc public func isSecondProperty() -> Bool {
        return self.bool(forKey: "isSecondProperty")
    }

}
```

**Call example inside UICollectionViewController sub class**

```
@implementation CollectionViewController {
    Settings* _settings;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _settings = [[Settings alloc] initWithDictionary:someDictionary];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([_settings isFirstProperty]) {
//Do something with cell according to firstProperty
} else if ([_settings isSecondProperty]) {
//Do something with cell according to secondProperty
} 

return cell;
}

@end
```

**Crash Report**

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Crashed Thread: 0

Application Specific Information:
               > customProperties

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   <unknown>                       0x103087e44         <redacted>
1   <unknown>                       0x102e1bbbc         <redacted>
2   UIKitCore                       0x185b6ff30         -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:]
3   UIKitCore                       0x185a68f44         -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
4   UIKitCore                       0x1859bcb3c         -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
5   UIKitCore                       0x1859cf470         -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
6   QuartzCore                      0x187132790         CA::Layer::layout_if_needed
7   UIKitCore                       0x185a33a18         -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
8   <unknown>                       0x102e13e44         <redacted>
9   UIKitCore                       0x1859c819c         +[UIView _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
10  <unknown>                       0x102e13ca0         <redacted>
11  <unknown>                       0x102e14e3c         <redacted>
12  <unknown>                       0x102e16618         <redacted>
13  UIKitCore                       0x185b52c00         -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:deselectPrevious:performCustomSelectionAction:]
14  UIKitCore                       0x185eec844         -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:]
15  UIKitCore                       0x185a36dd0         [inlined] forwardTouchMethod
16  UIKitCore                       0x185a36dd0         forwardTouchMethod
17  UIKitCore                       0x1859a624c         _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
18  UIKitCore                       0x1859d8d88         -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:]
19  UIKitCore                       0x1859e5f28         -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
20  UIKitCore                       0x185b95e30         -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
21  UIKitCore                       0x1859b913c         __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
22  UIKitCore                       0x1859adf28         __processEventQueue
23  UIKitCore                       0x1859b33d4         __eventFetcherSourceCallback
24  CoreFoundation                  0x1834540cc         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
25  CoreFoundation                  0x183464d8c         __CFRunLoopDoSource0
26  CoreFoundation                  0x18339f094         __CFRunLoopDoSources0
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1833a48a0         __CFRunLoopRun
28  CoreFoundation                  0x1833b8464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
29  GraphicsServices                0x19ef5c388         GSEventRunModal
30  UIKitCore                       0x185d5b5cc         -[UIApplication _run]
31  UIKitCore                       0x185ad9f70         UIApplicationMain
32  <unknown>                       0x102ff762c         <redacted>
33  <unknown>                       0x1034c5aa4         <redacted>
```

Comment: Because of line 2 in third file? We can't guess what's wrong without the culprit code...

Comment: @Larme I have updated the question with the lines of code

Comment: What does the crash report say? Can you post it?

Comment: @calimarkus updated the crash report

Comment: Have you tried to symbolize this crash report? You need your original `.dsym` from the build you uploaded to the AppStore. That way you would see your apps symbols instead of `<unknown>` in the crash report.

Comment: Also what does self.bool refer to? This isn’t shown in your code snippets.